# Connect database in dash_auth.BasicAuth

Tags: python

How to connect the database (which stored the username and password) and able to get from the dash_auth.BasicAuth?

Normally, the username and password will be stored in `VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS` and connect as per below:

```
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = {
                                'user': 'pwd',
                                'usera': 'pwd1'

                                    }

auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(app, VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS)
```

If let say currently all the username and password is stored in a database, can I use the same way `dash_auth.BasicAuth` to connect? How to do?

Or any other method I can connect the database to get the user login access?

Comment: This isn't really related to the <sql> _language_. You'd better replace that tag with the one for the dbms you're using - to get better attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

Solution:

```
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = df_userpwd.set_index('username')['password'].to_dict()
```

Perform the connect to database and query as usual, then convert the dataframe to dictionary.